# Share TF records of sensitive data

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I just finished Tensorflow detection research and would like to make some data available with my paper. However, the images are sensitive and therefore I was thinking to share the TF records for training and testing instead. Is it (easily) possible to reverse-engineer the image data from the TF records?

I couldn't find an answer but would think it should be possible, as the serialisation is not done in a random or encrypted way. If it's possible, what would you recommend to share instead for the purpose of transparency?

Comment: What would the purpose of sharing that data be? If it's illustrative then people need to be able to see the images to understand how the network performs. By obscuring the images you'd be missing the point of the illustration exercise! Your best bet might be to just detail the model performance metrics and illustrate the modelling process in a figure that uses a pixelated example image.

Comment: The aim is to allow readers to verify the models. I am essentially running a comparison between the TF2 zoo models. I am using quite standard hyper-parameters and don't want to focus too much on the fine tuning. By making the TF records available, readers can test their own hyper-parameter tuning on the data.

Comment: No, I don't think that's possible I'm afraid. The best I can think of would be to write a web interface for users to give possible hyper-parameters and for you to run the training server-side, but that's not without its problems.